# Xcode build environment variable for scheme that is running

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodeproj

I've been trying to find a way to access the scheme name from a Run Script build phase. I'm writing a CLI command that updates a user's Xcode project so I don't have the luxury of tinkering with the Xcode user interface. I have been using Cocoapod's Xcodeproj dependency to update the build settings.

The first port of call is Xcode's build settings environment variables which do not contain the scheme. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference

I thought I would be able to do it programmatically via Xcodeproj dependency, but it appears the environment variables it sets are for the run-time application, not the build settings environment variables. See here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/XCScheme/EnvironmentVariables

Apple's documentation on schemes makes no suggestion for this predicament:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/customizing-the-build-schemes-for-a-project

**QUESTION:**
I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for obtaining the scheme name that is running from a Run Script build phase? Some setting I could apply programmatically using Xcodeproj or another tool to configure the project that could pull the scheme name as a value at build time?

I don't want to hardcode the value into the script as this would require generating multiple scripts in the build phases for each scheme.

Comment: What does "from a build phase script" mean? Do you mean this  is a Run Script build phase?

Comment: hey @matt, I mean "Build Phases" run script phase. I've updated the question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: So did you check the checkbox that outputs all the build-time environment variables to which your script has access?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have also ran "xcodebuild -project Runner.xcodeproj -scheme "development" -showBuildSettings" to see what is available, and scheme is not a variable. I've also checked the build settings reference as mentioned which does not contain the scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scheme isn't really a "thing"; it is merely a unification of several other aspects of the build operation. The particular aspect you probably want is the *configuration*, which is available as the `CONFIGURATION` build environment variable. In a bash script, for example, you can include a line such as

```
if [ $CONFIGURATION = "MyWonderfulConfiguration" ]; then
```

You can create configurations in the Project editor, and you can tie each scheme to its own configuration in the Scheme editor.

#### Configuration:

[image]

#### Scheme:

[image]

#### Environment variables:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @matt. You've inspired me to change the way the CLI works. I'll be using the build configuration rather than the scheme.